# Bold the paragraph after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="box">
<p class="b">item 1</p>
<p class="b">item 2</p>
<p class="b">item 3</p>
<p class="b">item 4</p>
<p class="b">item 5</p>
</div>
```

How to bold the selected paragraph after clicked? 
For example, if I click 'item 2', only the item 2 will bold after I clicked

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: click "item2" when "item 2" is not a link? then the only solution would be JS, otherwise CSS would do the job for you

Comment: I have tried using css.
#box p.static:active{ 
 font-weight: 800; 
}
The specified paragraph bold but only for a while, i want permanent after click a paragraph.

Comment: whats wrong with onclick="this.style.fontWeight = 'bold'" ? he didnt said its a website or app so i assume there is no bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function makeBold(el) {
    el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}

var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i<len; i++){
    paragraphs[i].onclick = function(){
        makeBold(this);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aA5g8/).

Or, if you'd prefer to toggle the font-weight:

```
function toggleBold(el) {
    el.style.fontWeight = el.style.fontWeight == 'bold' ? 'normal' : 'bold';
}

var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i<len; i++){
    paragraphs[i].onclick = function(){
        toggleBold(this);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aA5g8/1/).

Or, if you'd prefer to have only *one* paragraph in bold text (clicking a second paragraph returns other `p` elements to a non-bold state):

```
function toggleBold(el) {
    var siblings = el.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0, len = siblings.length; i<len; i++){
        if (siblings[i] == el){
            el.style.fontWeight = el.style.fontWeight == 'bold' ? 'normal' : 'bold';
        }
        else {
            siblings[i].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
        }
    }
}

var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i<len; i++){
    paragraphs[i].onclick = function(){
        toggleBold(this);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aA5g8/2/).

Comment: I have tried it. It is worked in the JS Fiddle. But not at chrome.

Comment: It does work in Chrome, that's the browser I wrote this answer in. Have you placed your `script` element at the bottom of the page, before the closing `</body>` tag? Does the DOM exist at the point at which your JavaScript is running?

Comment: Third solution is definitely what I wanted. But still, it is not working at chrome. I did place the <script> tag before closing </body>. The is another answer posted by Jameson is worked for me... but not like the solution you gave in the third one.

Comment: Can you reproduce at JS Fiddle? Include the relevant ([simplified/sscce](http://sscce.org/)) mark-up from with the `body` element. There's no reason (that I can see) that it shouldn't work, so possibly there's something else wrong that's causing problems.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aA5g8/2/
This is the working in JS Fiddle, but still not at my chrome?? why?

Comment: Showing me my own demo isn't going to help diagnose your problems. Compose a demo that reproduces your own set-up, then we can look into it.

Comment: Ok bro, I know where is the problem....Thanks for your answer, you really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="b" onclick="GetBold(this)">item 2</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function GetBold(current)
{
   var array = document.getElementsByClassName('p');

   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
        array[i].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
   }

   current.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```

Comment: Please don't suggest in-line JavaScript; it works, yes, but it's terribly intrusive on the mark-up and an absolute nightmare to maintain once you've got more than one or two functions to run. It really isn't worth the pain (this is just advice, rather than down-voting).

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$('.b').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'font-weight':'bold'})
})
```